# Should setting mutual references in hibernate happen within a unit of work or can it be done outside the unit of work?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

By unit of work I mean the start of a transaction to the end of a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can set them even outside of a unit of work. Only if you need to propagate the changes to the DB, you will need an open `EntityManager` and a transaction as well.

Comment: This isn't really related to transactions but more on how entities reference one another. In a @ManyToOne relationship, do you still set references to the parent entity or only the owning entity? Which do you persist in the db? I tried persisting the many side but I got a null pointer exception.